# проблема с choosen select

Tags: php, mysql

Поставил choosen select. Данные селекта берутся из базы следующим кодом

```
<select name="code" required class="chzn-select" style="width:550px; ">
    <option></option>
    <?php
include('../connect.php');
$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM goods");
    $result->bindParam(':userid', $res);
    $result->execute();
    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){
?>
    <option value=""><?php echo $row['goodname']; echo $row['shcode']; ?></option>
    <?php
            }
        ?>
  </select>
```

Здесь первый параметр - наименование товара, а второй - данные штрих кода. 
Все работает отлично, но не устраивает одно: когда пользователь вводит первые буквы, то `select` ищет только по первому параметру. В нашем случае он делает выбор только из наименований товара. А если ввести номера штрих кода, он выдает, что нету совпадений. Хотелось бы, чтоб он выводил и по первому значению, и по второму. Можно ли как-то реализовать это?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос в данном случае относится к JS плагину Chosen, php и mySQL тут ни при чем.

На странице плагина http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html имеется список опций. Параметр `search_contains` по умолчанию выставлен в значение `false`, и в этом случае Chosen начинает поиск с начала слова или, точнее, строки.

Чтобы Chosen искал так, как вам нужно, выставьте параметр `search_contains` в значение `true`. Тогда плагин будет искать совпадения в любом месте.

Comment: Ну спасибо ! Попробую. И за "поправку" тоже спасибо

Comment: Чтобы понять, о чем идет речь, пришлось загуглить часть имени класса "chzn". Легче отвечать, когда есть все данные.